# SelectLists in ASP.NET MVC assigning values to model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My question pertains to ASP.NET MVC 4.

**I have this code in an action method:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     var allProfiles = db.Profiles.ToList();
     var profsSelectList = new SelectList(allProfiles, "Id", "ProfileName");
     ViewBag.allProfiles = profsSelectList;
     return View();
}
```

**My View Has this:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("allProfiles")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
</div>
```

My goal is to provide a DropDownList that contains allProfiles.ProfileName as
the text for each select item.
When they select one of them, the "Id" property is assigned to Model.Author.
When the form is submitted, I expect the POST method to show a "Message" whose
author contains that integer.

My DropDownList correctly displays the list of ProfileNames. But the form submission
always sets Model.Author to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a fair poor way to pass model values to a view.  That's the point of creating a dedicated viewmodel.  Since it looks like you have a number of values you want submitted on the form.  Then pass the the model to your form and use the html helper methods editorfor,... to generate the elements on your page.  In your post controller action, pass the entire viewmodel back to the controller.  The default model binder should hook up all the values for you.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my own problem.

In order for a selectlist, which exists in your viewbag, to become a dropdown list who's value
sets a property of your Model ( in the view ), the following is the solution:

**The GET Create action method**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var allProfiles = db.Profiles.ToList();
    var profsSelectList = new SelectList(allProfiles, "Id", "ProfileName");
    ViewBag.allProfiles = profsSelectList;
    return View();
}
```

**The View creating the dropdown list**

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Author, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.allProfiles)
</div>
```

And there you have it.

Comment: To simply it, you can drop the .ToList() from the first line (`SelectList(...)` accepts IEnumerable, so no need for the extra overhead of creating a `List<T>` and the helper can be shortened to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Author, ViewBag.allProfiles)`